# Is Jaden Smith's "Cabin Fever" video seen on the Tonight Show with Jimmy Fallon no longer available? If so, why?

Tags: music-video

I recall a premier of some kind or other of a Jaden Smith video of *Cabin Fever* sung on a stage in the mountains as the sun set, shown on The Tonight Show with Jimmy Fallon

I can't find it in either the Tonight Show nor the Jaden YouTube channels, and in all popular press news articles of the time the YouTube links are now broken.

Is this video now no longer available? If so, is there any information why?

[image]

Source: [fallontonight.tumblr.com](https://fallontonight.tumblr.com/post/625810014818451456/jaden-gets-groovy-in-his-performance-of-cabin)

[image: Musical guest JADEN performs “Cabin Fever” for The Tonight Show. S7 E180 | 08/06/20 "Sorry, video is no longer available"]

Source: NBC.com's [Musical guest JADEN performs “Cabin Fever” for The Tonight Show. S7 E180 | 08/06/20 "Sorry, video is no longer available"](https://www.nbc.com/the-tonight-show/video/jaden-cabin-fever/4211297)

Comment: not enough rep to create the jaden-smith tag